# CodeIgniter - SQL Query AND clause with table columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, apostrophe

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm struggling with the Active Record Class and the apostrophes it adds to my query:

This is the query that CodeIgniter outputs (Via enable_profiler):

```
 SELECT `login`.`idlogin`, `login`.`username`, `login`.`password`
 FROM (`login`, `pessoa`)
 WHERE `login`.`username` =  'user1'
 AND `login`.`password` =  'pass1'
 AND `pessoa`.`nBI` =  'login.pessoa_nBI'
 LIMIT 1
```

user1 and pass1 are strings from a login form (ignore the password in plain cleartext). This produces 0 results.

However the correct query, i.e., the result I want is:

```
SELECT `login`.`idlogin` , `login`.`username` , `login`.`password`
FROM (`login` , `pessoa`)
WHERE `login`.`username` = 'user1'
AND `login`.`password` = 'pass1'
AND `pessoa`.`nBI` = login.pessoa_nBI
LIMIT 1
```

Only difference is the penultimate line, login.pessoa_nBI isn't surrounded by an apostrophe.

Which produces out one result, as it should.
Database is MySQL.

Edit: Here is Active Record code:

```
$this -> db -> select('login.idlogin, login.username, login.password');
$this -> db -> from('login,pessoa);
$this -> db -> where('login.username', $username);
$this -> db -> where('login.password', $password);
$this -> db -> where('pessoa.nBI', login.pessoa_nBI');
$this -> db -> limit(1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your actual active record query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activerecord [`where`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) provides a parameter so codigniter does not escape your data

```
$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. 
// If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or 
// table names with backticks.

$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

---

You can use a [join](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) though for your query

```
$this->db->select('l.idLogin, l.username, l.password');
$this->db->from('login AS l');
$this->db->join('pessoa', 'pessoa.nBI = l.pessoa_nBI');
$this->db->where('l.username', 'usernam');
etc..
```

Comment: Yes. Join solves the problem. Does join have a significant performance hit compared to what I did?

Comment: profile each query with `EXPLAIN`, i believe your query was doing a join it just wasn't using a JOIN statement